# Cornerstone version control

Tags: version-control, repository, cornerstone

I am doing an iOS internship and the company uses cornerstone for version control. I am pretty unfamiliar with this program. Does anyone know any good tutorials to get me started? I am familiar with git I just need to figure out how to add a new repository. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am also new in cornerstone. I need to create a new repository also. But searching a lot i did not find any helpful topic. At last I fund their customer "support" link. Lets try to find from here.

http://www.zennaware.com/cornerstone/support.php